# I got an issue in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

i cant solve this problem.Can anyone help.I am totally a beginner.The result shows

```
  File "C:/Users/y/PycharmProjects/learn1/haha.py", line 72, in <module>
    gameloop()
  File "C:/Users/y/PycharmProjects/learn1/haha.py", line 58, in gameloop
    cow.cow()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cow' referenced before assignment
```

I need help.Feel free to jugde my code skills.
I am trying to build my own invisble cow.That is a really cool game.
i have try to fix the problem but i cant fix it.so i need your help plz.please comment to tell what the problem is.thanks

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 600))
white = (255, 255, 255)

pygame.display.set_caption('Invisible Cow')
cow_image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\y\Pictures\cow5.jpg')
class Cow(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        dist = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\y\Pictures\cow5.jpg')

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dist = dist

    def cow(self):
        self.x = x
    def cow_draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
import random

y = random.randint(0, 600)
x = random.randint(0, 960)
cow = Cow(x, y)

cow.cow()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def gameloop():
    game_over = False
    game_close = False
    while not game_over :

        screen.fill(white)
        while game_close == True:
            dis.fill(blue)
            message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", red)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    game_over = True
                    game_close = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    gameloop()



            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

                quit()

            cow.cow()
            if cow.x < 0:
                y = random.randint(0, 600)
                x = random.randint(0, 960)
                cow = Cow(x, y)

            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
            cow.cow_draw(screen)
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                game_close

            pygame.display.update()

            clock.tick(40)
gameloop()
'''
```

Comment: We need more information about your program before we can help you.

Comment: I have post my code.Thanks

Comment: please update title with more specific details. Compiler / interpreter output probably includes a line number, copy paste the full output message instead of partial output.

Comment: i have updated.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what your program does, but the reason you are getting the error message is because you are instantiating `cow = Cow(x, y)` in an `if` block, but you are calling `cow.cow_draw(screen)`, which is a method of that instance outside of the if statement, before the `if` block runs. So effectively, whats happening is you are trying to call the method without instantiating first. To fix the problem, you can simply move `cow.cow_draw(screen)` inside the if block.
Something i want to point out, since you are creating a different instance of the `Cow`, it would make more sense to use a different name to the first one, maybe `cow1`?

```
if cow.x < 0:
      y = random.randint(0, 600)
      x = random.randint(0, 960)
      cow1 = Cow(x, y)

      screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
      cow1.cow_draw(screen)
```

This will get rid of the error. Also, couple of other things i noticed. First, all the `import`'s as usually defined at the top. Second, you call `pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\y\Pictures\cow5.jpg')` twice. Instead of that, you can simply define it once and use it multiple times. So your class could look like this:

```
class Cow(object):
    def __init__(self, img, x=0, y=0):
        dist = 0
        self.image = img

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dist = dist
```

And while making a instance, you can pass in image variable as first argument.

```
cow = Cow(cow_image, 10, 10)
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The error is being caused by the lack of the lack of the `global` keyword in the `gameloop()` function. The reassignment of `cow` in the if block is clearly just to create a new `cow` if the old one goes off the left of the screen. It is intended to update the external global `cow`, but it is causing python instead to decide `cow` is a local variable which hides the globally scoped `cow`.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for correcting me, although the solution i mentioned works as well

Comment: If that is the case, re-assigning the position values probably makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue. You need to use the `global` keyword on the variable `cow` in your `gameloop()` function. The fix is at the end, but first I will explain the issue.

In your `gameloop()` function you have this line:

```
cow = Cow(x, y)
```

Whenever you have an assignment in a function, that causes python to determine that you want a local scope variable inside that function unless it had previously been indicated as `global` by use of the global keyword. Once it decides that there is a local variable with that name, all accesses to this variable in the function (even before the assignment) are assumed to reference that local variable. That means that this local variable hides any global variable that has the same name and the higher scoped global variable with that name is not visible even to be read from.

That means that in that function when you try to do the `cow.cow()` it is saying that the local cow variable is not yet initialised, because it isn't.

If you want to be able to change a globally scoped variable inside your function you have to tell it by using the `global` keyword. Add this at the top of your `gameloop()` function:

```
def gameloop():
   global cow
   ...
```